# FACEBOOK like button and meta tag 'og:site_name' not showing correctly

Tags: facebook, meta-tags

I´ve inserted a FACEBOOK like button succesfully, except that the meta tag 'og:site_name' is not working...:

On my facebook page, it shows the name of the main domain (http://www.domain.com) and not the content of the meta tag 'og:site_name' (FAN CLUB)

I've research everything there is to research without success... Something so simple(?) Am i missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Feeding your URL through the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) should clear Facebook's caching of your URL and refresh any changes you have made.  Try passing your URL to the debugger and it should be refreshed to the correct value.

The debugger will also direct you to any other problems you may have with regard to integrating your URL into the Open Graph Protocol...

Comment: ya i know about the debugger.. tried it before posting here... nothing... i'm starting to believe that maybe this is normal behavior from FACEBOOK...

Comment: Can you please post a link to the problematic URL?

Comment: Seems to me like it is taking the value of `og:title` - http://i.imgur.com/eitHQ.png

Comment: maybe you coould help clarify it: below the value og:title is where og:site_name should go, right? in this case 'FAN CLUB' and not the url...